# transfer application which uses composer from wamp to linux

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, wamp

I have a native php application where I used composer in order to use some libraries. Now I want to transfer the application from wamp to linux online server. Do I need to install composer to linux also and re-run it? Or just the files as they are?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try instead of open the question?

Comment: If you transfer the `vendor` director you won't strictly need composer installed, but you really should. If nothing else it'll save you FTPing the thousands of files that are likely in the directory one-by-one. It'll also let you install updated sets of packages much more quickly when you add one.

Comment: Ok thank you for the quick answer! I have an issue with the paths and I thought maybe this was the reason..